# Acer Aspire runs slow, black screens after logging in

Tags: windows, laptop, acer-aspire, black-screen-of-death

I have and Acer Aspire laptop that's about 3-4 months old that is now running super slow.

I takes five minutes to get to the login page and after logging in, it freezes right after saying welcome.

After another five minutes the desktop goes black and I can't do anything at all.

I've tried to repair my computer (F8), restoring several times and also restarting it several times.

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried to boot into safe mode? Have you tried to reset your bio's to default?

Answer (score 0):

First try Safe Mode and reseting defaults in the BIOS, Acer it is F2 for BIOS and F9 to load defaults, followed by F10 to save changes.  If the unit boots safe mode then you can use msconfig to disable all startup applications and all non-Microsoft services temporarily.

If you have no data and don't care about going back to factory defaults you can do so by rebooting the computer and hitting Alt + F10 repeatly at the Acer logo.

If you see a white progress bar with some text that says Loading Windows you have successfully entered the recovery partition, follow the prompts to restore the os to factory defaults.

If after doing a complete factory restore and the unit still exhibits the same issue, it is a hardware issue and it will need to be serviced by Acer if it is still under warranty.

Comment: Since OP can get to login page, he can get into safe mode by pressing shift and restart to access advanced settings on next startup and booting into safe mode.